# Use nginx-proxy and wordpress in docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, proxy, docker-compose

I try to host some wordpress with an nginx proxy above:
This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:0.4.0
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      # SSL Certificates
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysupersite.com/cert.pem:/etc/nginx/certs/site.com.crt:ro
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysupersite.com/privkey.pem:/etc/nginx/certs/site.com.key:ro

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:4.8.1-php5.6-apache
    expose:
      - 80
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html:/var/www/html
    restart: always
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mysql
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=dev
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=passwd
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=db
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=mysupersite.com,www.mysupersite.com
```

Everything seems to start well. I have 2 running containers. 
But I'm not able to visit my website on `https://mysupersite.com` in my browser. 
What part am I missing? Do I need extra configuration somewhere?

I see this error in my browser:

```
The page isn’t redirecting properly
```

output o `cur -L -v https://www.mysupersite.com` is the following:

```
* Connection #0 to host www.mysupersite.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://www.mysupersite.com/'
* Found bundle for host www.mysupersite.com: xx [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host www.mysupersite.com
* Connected to www.mysupersite.com (IP) port 443 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.mysupersite.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.9.12
< Date: Tue, 22 Aug 2017 07:33:22 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.31
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=xxx; path=/
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< X-Pingback: http://www.mysupersite.com/xmlrpc.php
< Location: https://www.mysupersite.com/
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
<
* Connection #0 to host www.mysupersite.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://www.mysupersite.com/'
* Found bundle for host www.mysupersite.com: xxxx [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host www.mysupersite.com
* Connected to www.mysupersite.com (IP) port 443 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.mysupersite.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.9.12
< Date: Tue, 22 Aug 2017 07:33:23 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.31
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=xxxx; path=/
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< X-Pingback: http://www.mysupersite.com/xmlrpc.php
< Location: https://www.mysupersite.com/
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
<
* Connection #0 to host www.mysupersite.com left intact
* Maximum (50) redirects followed
curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"`

Comment: I've edit it. I tried that too. I've also added www.mysupersite.ocm

Comment: @TarunLalwani It's redirecting fine so when I visit on :80 it's going to 443 and it's SSL https but the site isn't showed. The 'redirect' is wrong.

Comment: Do a `curl -v -L https://www.mysupersite.ocm` and post the logs in your question

Comment: @TarunLalwani I'll do: I'll see already a '< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"